# JQuery .load event causes Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, load, internal-server-error

I tried to improve the speed of my website by loading most pages right at the beginning. Therefore I created a number of div-tags and wanted to load the other files right into them by using the load event of jQuery.

Here is my source code:

```
<script>
function LoadPages(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#content1").load("main.php",function(){
            $("#content2").load("page2.php");
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

When loading my website ther occurs an Internal Server Error 500. In fact, I like to load up to 10 pages, but the error occurs with 2 also. I call the function LoadPages() right after I define the divs in the body, so the divs exist when I call the function.

Note: If I only load one page, the code works.
The code also works if the callback function of the first load event is empty, but if the callback is not empty (for example just an alert statement) then the error appears again. Does anyone have an idea what could cause the error?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: An internal server error is just that, a server error. You need to investigate that before you look at your javascript, which looks "okay".

Comment: Q: Why is your DOM ready function inside a function? Who (and why) is calling `LoadPages()`?

Comment: An "internal server error" comes from... the server!  It cannot be JavaScript related...

Comment: Your function must be inside the document ready, not the inverse

Comment: @Jack: So how do I find out more about that error? I have not much experience by investigating server-side errors.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: The function gets called by a script right after I definded the div-tags where I want to load the content. Do you have any better solution for loading the content into the divs?

Comment: Have you developer tools open, usually F12. Look at the debug console or the network tab when your function runs. You should be able to see the actual error responses from the server.

Comment: Yes, I have it open, in the Network panel, I can see 1 response but that's just the 500 Internal Server Error again. Maybe you can see more? http://www.ttc-oberpullendorf.net/neu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a test suggestion, but is too big for a comment:

1. There is no need for the DOM ready as (from your comments) your calling code is defining the elements, so they must exist.

e.g. this will do

```
<script>
    function LoadPages(){
        $("#content1").load("main.php",function(){
            $("#content2").load("page2.php");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Note: redundant DOM ready handlers do nothing harmful, as they fire instantly, but they waste space so are best avoided.

2. Test your code by reusing the page you know works (e.g. `main.php` in both loads)

e.g.

```
<script>
    function LoadPages(){
        $("#content1").load("main.php",function(){
            $("#content2").load("main.php");
        });
    }
</script>
```

3. Test you pages directly by putting the URLs in your browser

e.g.

```
http://www.domain.com/main.php
http://www.domain.com/page2.php
```

and see what the problems are with the pages.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your ideas. I left the .ready statement away, now it works with two pages, but whenever I want to load the third page, the error appears again.
To your third point: The pages work as they should when I call them.

Comment: I tried it before and the error occured, Now I tried it again and the error was gone. Weird thing. I'll now try it with all files and see if it works. Edit: I now tried it with 4 files and the error occurs. (even if I choose the same file four times)

Comment: If you use option 3, do any files give an error? try them all rapidly in different browser tabs.

Comment: Please show your full code for the loading and an example of the code in one of the pages. I am at a loss as this appears to be a server fault (as in it simply cannot serve up the files under load)

Comment: You can find the page at http://www.ttc-oberpullendorf.net/neu
or what exactly do you want me to do? I now loaded only 3 files, so that you can see the page

Comment: Oddly, the very first time I hit your server I got a 500 error for the first page!

Comment: So you can't see the page now? Shall I reduce to load just one page?

Comment: I got it on refresh, but the point is your server is *really* unreliable at the moment.

Comment: Ok, then I can't do anything about it now. I tried it at localhost (without the database) and it works there. :/

Comment: this may be a file permission issue. make sure that the new files you have created have the right permissions for you to read/write/execute.